# Three.js getObjectByName delivers undefined

Tags: javascript, three.js

I started my first Three.js project. A solar system which you can see [here](http://www.never-mage.de/webgl).

I have a function `addCelestrialObject()` where I create the planets and I want this function to automatically create the orbit circles what it does for the planets but I want it also for moons.
So every Planet (mesh) becomes a name and I want to access this object to get its center position so I can add a circle to this position if I have a moon.
My problem is that the function `scene.getObjectByName(parent,true);` always delivers an `undefined`. You can see the `console.log(scene)` on my [example](http://www.never-mage.de/webgl) when you inspect the site.

```
function addCelestrialObject(name, type, parent, surface, bump, specular, 
    positionX, positionY, positionZ, size, clouds, drawcircle
) {
    var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    var group = new THREE.Group();
    loader.load(surface, function (texture) {

        var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(size, 32, 32);
        if (type == "sun") {
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture });
            material.shading = true;
        } else {
            var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map: texture, overdraw: 0.5 });
            material.shading = true;
            if (bump) {
                material.bumpMap = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(bump);
                material.bumpScale = 0.5;
            }
            if (specular) {
                material.specularMap = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(specular);
                material.specular = new THREE.Color(0x222222);
            }
        }
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        mesh.name = name;
        mesh.position.x = positionX;
        mesh.position.y = positionY;
        mesh.position.z = positionZ;
        objectControls.add(mesh);
        mesh.select = function () {
            var position = { x: controls.target.x, y: controls.target.y, z: controls.target.z };
            var target = { x: this.position.x, y: this.position.y, z: this.position.z };
            var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(position).to(target, 500);
            tween.easing(TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.InOut)
            tween.onUpdate(function () {
                controls.target.x = position.x;
                controls.target.y = position.y;
                controls.target.z = position.z;
                controls.dollyIn(2);
            });
            tween.start();
            controls.minDistance = size * 5;
        }
        onRenderFcts.push(function (delta, now) {
            mesh.rotateY(1 / 32 * delta)
        });
        group.add(mesh);
    });

    if (clouds == true) {
        var canvasResult = document.createElement('canvas')
        canvasResult.width = 1024
        canvasResult.height = 512
        var contextResult = canvasResult.getContext('2d')

        // load earthcloudmap
        var imageMap = new Image();
        imageMap.addEventListener("load", function () {
            // create dataMap ImageData for earthcloudmap
            var canvasMap = document.createElement('canvas')
            canvasMap.width = imageMap.width
            canvasMap.height = imageMap.height
            var contextMap = canvasMap.getContext('2d')
            contextMap.drawImage(imageMap, 0, 0)
            var dataMap = contextMap.getImageData(0, 0, canvasMap.width, canvasMap.height)

            // load earthcloudmaptrans
            var imageTrans = new Image();
            imageTrans.addEventListener("load", function () {
                // create dataTrans ImageData for earthcloudmaptrans
                var canvasTrans = document.createElement('canvas')
                canvasTrans.width = imageTrans.width
                canvasTrans.height = imageTrans.height
                var contextTrans = canvasTrans.getContext('2d')
                contextTrans.drawImage(imageTrans, 0, 0)
                var dataTrans = contextTrans.getImageData(0, 0, canvasTrans.width, canvasTrans.height)
                // merge dataMap + dataTrans into dataResult
                var dataResult = contextMap.createImageData(canvasMap.width, canvasMap.height)
                for (var y = 0, offset = 0; y < imageMap.height; y++) {
                    for (var x = 0; x < imageMap.width; x++, offset += 4) {
                        dataResult.data[offset + 0] = dataMap.data[offset + 0]
                        dataResult.data[offset + 1] = dataMap.data[offset + 1]
                        dataResult.data[offset + 2] = dataMap.data[offset + 2]
                        dataResult.data[offset + 3] = 255 - dataTrans.data[offset + 0]
                    }
                }
                // update texture with result
                contextResult.putImageData(dataResult, 0, 0)
                material.map.needsUpdate = true;
            })
            imageTrans.src = 'textures/earthcloudmaptrans.jpg';
        }, false);
        imageMap.src = 'textures/earthcloudmap.jpg';

        var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(size + 0.5, 32, 32)
        var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
            map: new THREE.Texture(canvasResult),
            side: THREE.DoubleSide,
            transparent: true,
            opacity: 1,
            shading: true,
        })
        var cloudMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        cloudMesh.position.x = positionX;
        cloudMesh.position.y = positionY;
        cloudMesh.position.z = positionZ;
        group.add(cloudMesh);
        onRenderFcts.push(function (delta, now) {
            cloudMesh.rotateY(1 / 16 * delta)
        });
    }
    if (drawcircle == true) {
        //circle
        var radius = Math.abs(distance(0, positionX, 0, positionZ));
        segments = 64;
        materialLine = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00a8ff });

        geometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry(radius, segments);
        // Remove center vertex
        geometry.vertices.shift();
        circle = new THREE.Line(geometry, materialLine);
        circle.rotation.x = 1.571;
        if (parent) {
            var object = scene.getObjectByName(parent, true);

            //circle.position.x=object.position.x;
            //circle.position.y=object.position.y;
            //circle.position.z=object.position.z;
        }
        group.add(circle);
    }
    scene.add(group);
}
```

Comment: the function takes only one argument `.getObjectByName (name)` which is a string. is `parent` a string?

Comment: Yes parent is a string and i tried with only one argument but it also gives undefined back. I saw that the second argument was for reverse searching or something like that. Can it be that getObjectByName only finds objects that are direct childs of the scene and can't find objects that are in a group under another object?